# Nstimer with method that have variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I have a method that have input variable and I need to schedule this method using`NSTimer` 
Unfortunately when I try to make the idea I got some error 
My code is the following:

My method:

```
-(void)movelabel:(UILabel *)label {
}
```

I make my scheduling using the following:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(movelabel:myLbabeName) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

But, I got the following error:

```
error: expected ':' before ')' token
```

In other case (case of method without input variable i'm calling the timer like the following:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(myMethodNameWithoutVariable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you give to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` does not take arbitrary arguments. It should be either a selector without parameter or a selector with a single parameter of type `(NSTimer *)`.

That means you can't directly call `moveLabel:` with your parameter `myLbabeName`.

You could use the `userInfo` dictionary with an intermediary method like this:

(`timerRef` is a `NSTimer` class variable)

```
timerRef = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 
                               target:self 
                               selector:@selector(timerMovelabel:) 
                               userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myLbabeName 
                                                                    forKey:@"name"]
                                repeats:YES];
```

and

```
- (void)timerMovelabel:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self movelabel:[[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to stop the timer, keep a reference to it and call `[timerRef invalidate]`

Comment: I hadn't tried it with user info I will try this but it may be a great answer.. Thanks Jilouc I got a new thing how o use user info.. else I need to ask it somewhere.

Comment: hello i want to pass an integer with the method but i got the following error :" Passing argument 1 of 'dictionaryWithObject:forKey:' makes pointer from integer without a cast  " -- i have tried int, nsinteger, nsinteger *. but i got the same error

Comment: You must encapsulate it in a NSNumber : [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]. You can get the int value of a NSNumber using intValue.

Comment: can you explane by example plz?

Comment: Using the same names I've put in the answer above. Step 1: put a NSNumber in the dictionary [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:42] forKey:@"name"]. Step 2: in "timerMovelabel:" get an int with: [self movelabel:[[[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"name"] intValue]]

Comment: this what id did before but unfortunately in getting null valeu (or 0) in the variable

Comment: here my code    [NSNumber numberWithInt:42];
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01  
   target:self  selector:@selector(timerMovelabel:)  userInfo:
   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:42] forKey:@"number"]    my timer method - (void)timerMovelabel:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self direction:[[[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"number"] intValue]];
} and my method to call is 

- (void) direction:(NSInteger *)dir 
{  
 NSLog(@"%d",dir);
} also i have tried this - (void) direction:(int)dir

Comment: Your method should be - (void)direction:(NSInteger)dir { ... }

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ':' after the parameter, i.e.

```m
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(movelabel:myLbabeName:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Please explain why he need to add ":" after parameter? in objc parameters are saparated by ":" and he don't need to add ":" sign. Actually he can't use any parameter with selector except id and for that he only need to use @selector(movelabel:)...No extra parameter...

Comment: Because Objective-C has such syntax

Comment: dude this is incorrect syntax coz of this @Mouhamad get an error..and ofcourse you will get an error because your method will accept two parameters now and it will not get correspond declaration of Action

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass ur lable as parameter with selector...There should be either one parameter which will be id or no parameter..

here you have to use

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(movelabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

or

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(movelabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

if you use the first on then you can get you timer and action defination will be like

```
- (void) moveLable :(id)sender {
}
```

sender will be timer.

anyways why you need your lable as parameter. you can directly access your lable if you declare it in .h file.